# get user ip insteade of application load balancer ip laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ip, aws-application-load-balancer

I run laravel application on AWS, I use Application Load Balancer.

```
Route::get('/what-is-my-ip', function(){ 
    return request()->ip();
});
```

When I run this code, my ip doesn't show, it shows the load balancer's ip addresses.

My TrustProxies Middleware

```
protected $proxies = '*';

protected $headers =
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

Comment: For ALB you only need `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;` for the headers. Also make sure the `TrustProxies` middleware is set in your `Http/Kernel.php` file (I think it's commented out by default)

Comment: I changed the header to be

    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;

in kernel 

  protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,        
    ];
but still not working